# Create additional ranking that resets based on specific value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to have a rank that resets to 1 based on the appearance of a value. More specifically shown in the table below, I have a standard ranking partitioned by id, but I want to also have the "session_rank" column that resets to 1 whenever the row takes the value "new session" in the session field:

```
| timestamp                   | id     | previoustime                | previousid | rnk | session     | session_rank |
|-----------------------------|--------|-----------------------------|------------|-----|-------------|--------------|
| 2019-10-16 19:00:00.000 UTC | abc123 | Null                        | Null       | 1   |             | 1            |
| 2019-10-16 19:01:00.000 UTC | abc123 | 2019-10-16 19:00:00.000 UTC | abc123     | 2   |             | 2            |
| 2019-10-16 19:02:00.000 UTC | abc123 | 2019-10-16 19:01:00.000 UTC | abc123     | 3   |             | 3            |
| 2019-10-16 21:00:00.000 UTC | abc123 | 2019-10-16 19:02:00.000 UTC | abc123     | 4   | new session | 1            |
| 2019-10-16 21:01:00.000 UTC | abc123 | 2019-10-16 21:00:00.000 UTC | abc123     | 5   |             | 2            |
| 2019-10-16 19:00:00.000 UTC | def456 | 2019-10-16 21:01:00.000 UTC | abc123     | 1   |             | 1            |
| 2019-10-16 19:01:00.000 UTC | def456 | 2019-10-16 19:00:00.000 UTC | def456     | 2   |             | 2            |
| 2019-10-16 19:02:00.000 UTC | def456 | 2019-10-16 19:01:00.000 UTC | def456     | 3   |             | 3            |
| 2019-10-16 19:03:00.000 UTC | def456 | 2019-10-16 19:02:00.000 UTC | def456     | 4   |             | 4            |
```

I'm aware I should be using a window function and have toyed around with a `ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` statement in my over clause but haven't quite got it to work.
Here's what I have:

```
SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, sessiongroup ORDER BY timestamp) newrank
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    FIRST_VALUE(newrnk ignore nulls) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) sessiongroup
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, session ORDER BY timestamp ) AS newrnk
    FROM (
      SELECT
        *,
        CASE
          WHEN id=lastid AND TIMESTAMP_DIFF(timestamp, lasttime, minute)>90 THEN "new session"
        ELSE
        ""
      END
        session
      FROM (
        SELECT
          timestamp,
          id,
          LAG(timestamp) OVER(ORDER BY id, timestamp) lasttime,
          LAG(id) OVER(ORDER BY id, timestamp) lastid,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp ) AS rnk
        FROM
          `table`
        WHERE
          timestamp >= "2019-10-16 00:00:00"
          AND timestamp < "2019-10-18 00:00:00"
          AND id IS NOT NULL
    ))))
ORDER BY
  id,
  timestamp
```

There's also the question of whether this is even the optimal method to use in achieving the desired result, as I'm using BigQuery and constant bump up against the memory limit using `OVER` and `ORDER BY`. Is there a more memory efficient solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ts, id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, session ORDER BY ts) rnk
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(new_session) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts) session
  FROM (
    SELECT *, IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ts, LAG(ts) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts), MINUTE) > 90, FALSE) new_session  
    FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  )
)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-10-16 19:00:00.000 UTC' ts, 'abc123' id UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-10-16 19:01:00.000 UTC', 'abc123' UNION ALL  
  SELECT '2019-10-16 19:02:00.000 UTC', 'abc123' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-10-16 21:00:00.000 UTC', 'abc123' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-10-16 21:01:00.000 UTC', 'abc123' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-10-16 19:00:00.000 UTC', 'def456' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-10-16 19:01:00.000 UTC', 'def456' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-10-16 19:02:00.000 UTC', 'def456' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-10-16 19:03:00.000 UTC', 'def456'  
)
SELECT ts, id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, session ORDER BY ts) rnk
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(new_session) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts) session
  FROM (
    SELECT *, IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ts, LAG(ts) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts), MINUTE) > 90, FALSE) new_session  
    FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  )
)
-- ORDER BY id, ts
```

with result

```
Row ts                      id      rnk  
1   2019-10-16 19:00:00 UTC abc123  1    
2   2019-10-16 19:01:00 UTC abc123  2    
3   2019-10-16 19:02:00 UTC abc123  3    
4   2019-10-16 21:00:00 UTC abc123  1    
5   2019-10-16 21:01:00 UTC abc123  2    
6   2019-10-16 19:00:00 UTC def456  1    
7   2019-10-16 19:01:00 UTC def456  2    
8   2019-10-16 19:02:00 UTC def456  3    
9   2019-10-16 19:03:00 UTC def456  4
```

Comment: I should add, the question is an example representative of the problem, which contains >10,000,000 data points, the solution needs to be generalisable.

Comment: not sure what do you mean! remove WITH section (which is presented here just for you to test and play with before applying to your real data) and use your `project.dataset.table`. I've just updated my answer to stress this out. Let m eknow if I am still missing something

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, it was speaking to memory concerns I voiced at the end of the question, but I've tested your solution and it works well enough that I can just append additional data a reasonable number of times. If I could be cheeky and squeeze in another small question, I remember that there exists a command to generate unique ids but can't find what it is. I wanted to use this to assign a new id for each instance (as defined by the `id` and each new `1` in the `rnk` field as shown above.)

Comment: Would the command and tried using the same structure as the `row_number` statement, but it doesn't support an over clause: `generate_uuid() OVER(PARTITION BY id, session ORDER BY timestamp) session_id`

Comment: Nevermind I've got it, combined the `generate_uuid` and then used `FIRST_VALUE` function using the `OVER` clause: `first_value(<generate_uuid variable name>) OVER(PARTITION BY cid, session ORDER BY timestamp) session_id`

Answer (score 0):

Use a cumulative `countif()` to assign the sessions:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id, grp order by timestamp) as with_session_counter
from (select t.*,
             countif(session = 'new session') over (partition by id order by timestamp) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```